# Does anybody use EmberJS/Handlebars with a Frontend Framework?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, handlebars.js, zurb-foundation

as I'm learning new things every day since I use EmberJS I wanted to ask if somebody is already using EmberJS with any Frontend Framework like `Foundation 4` or `Bootstrap` and how you handle the additional markup provided by `Handlebars` like the `<div/>` elements which are included when using the Ember.Handlebars.helpers `outlet` or `render`?

I try to integrate the Zurb `Foundation 4` Frontend Framework within my Ember Application and it seems to me that getting the grid to work smoothly and without errors is a bit more complicated than I thought... Is there an existing 'how-to' or any guideline for integrating a Frontend Framework?

Would be cool if anybody could point me in the right direction or give some examples/links to tutorials or something like that... thanks! :)

Comment: can you setup a jsbin of what you have tried so far? altough it's not working correctly, this will be easier to help out I guess

Comment: This is something I am seeing too. Most of the time increasing the specificity of the CSS selector fixes things for me.

Comment: @intuitivepixel it seems that I'm not able to set up a JSBin for this, as all I see is a bunch of errors in the Chrome console and no output at JSBin (see my miserable failure here: http://jsbin.com/akelin/1/edit)...

Comment: @DarshanSawardekar what do you excatly mean by "increase the specificity of the CSS selector"? Using more and more ids instead of classes? This would be very odd...

Comment: let me know if my answer did work for you

Comment: @intuitivepixel thanks, I'm now able to use and edit the JSBin example you gave me! I'm working on providing a proper example to describe my problem/needs.

Comment: ok, go for it and let me know if I can help further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I dont know in which step exactly you did get stuck I've created a working jsbin with the foundation zurb css from scratch. It shows a basic price table using css classes provided by the framework. (see [here](http://patterntap.com/code) for more markup examples)

And here for a [working demo](http://jsbin.com/ikehoq/4/edit) ember app.

Hope it helps you moving forward with your development.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and effort! The example looks good if I surf to http://jsbin.com/elawid but I can't get into the edit mode as all I see is the loading image an the page stuck... I'd add a screenshot if I could here within this comment, sorry I can't provide more information... (I'm using Google Chrome)

Comment: @herom, oh I had yesterday the same problem with another jsbin, will try to fix it, stay tuned

Comment: so, tested in Google Chrome, IE10 on 2 different desktop computers with different network connections and Google Chrome on Android and the console output is the same in all of them:

(1) `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL ... edit:350`, 
(2) `init ... navigation.js:11`, 
(3) `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined ... processor.js:42`

Do you think it's got something to do with JSBin itself? sorry for bothering you with this issue too....

Comment: @herom updated my answer with a new jsbin have a look, yes I guess it's a jsbin issues